# Are the logarithm rules and exponentiation rules (e.g. $a^{x+y}=a^xa^y$) axioms when talking about real numbers?

Tags: logarithms, exponentiation, real-numbers, axioms

Are the logarithm rules and exponentiation rules (e.g. $a^{x+y}=a^xa^y$) axioms when talking about real numbers?

I know many of them can be proved via induction for integers, but no professor has ever mentioned a proof of these 'rules' when having $\Bbb R$ as a domain.

Comment: No. Handle rationals first, then show true for reals (Dedekind cuts, for example).

Comment: @copper.hat Joe ... a EE discussing Dedekind cuts ... shocking ... ;-)) just kidding my friend. +1 for your comment.  Mark

Comment: @Dr.MV: :-). ${}{}{}$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They can be, but they don't have to be. One of the simplest setups is to define $\exp$ to be the unique function satisfying $\exp'=\exp$ and $\exp(0)=1$; then define $\ln$ to be the inverse of $\exp$; then define $a^x=\exp(x \ln(a))$ for $a>0$. Then the exponent and logarithm rules are theorems. Most of the proof of the rules is just elementary algebra; the tricky part is proving (from the definition above) the functional equation $\exp(x+y)=\exp(x)\exp(y)$.

Comment: If you are willing to take the ODE definition of $\exp$, the homomorphism property is straightforward to prove (assuming uniqueness, which is straightforward to establish).

Comment: One can also *define* the exponential functions as those anywhere-continuous functions satisfying $f(x+y)=f(x)f(y)$, but that leads right back to this property being sort of axiomatic.

Comment: @copper.hat It is indeed straightforward, but it is still analysis more than algebra (at least the way I did it), so I find it trickier than the rest of the argument.

Answer (score 3):

Walter Rudin's Principles of Mathematical Analysis addresses exactly this in Chapter 1. Problem 6. Which outlines:

Fix $b> 1$. If $p = m/n = p/q$ ($m,n,p,q$ integers) prove $(b^m)^{\frac{1}{n}} = (b^p)^{\frac{1}{q}} $.

This shows that $b$ to a rational power is well and consistently defined.

($b^{\frac{1}{n}}$ had been previously defined to be the one postive n-th root which had previously been proven to exist and be unique.)

b) proof $b^{r + s} = b^rb^r $ for rational r, s.

c) And this is the crux.

If x is real, define B(x) to be the set of all numbers $b^t$ where t is rational and t<=x.  Prove that

$b^r = sup B(r)$ when r is rational.

This shows we can define $b^x = sup B(x)$ is an extended definition into the reals.

d) Prove $b^{x+y} = b^xb^y$ for real x, y.

Problem 7, is to define the logarithm for real numbers and that it is unique.

Do you want details of the solution?

Comment: there's a typo with the exponent variables in b)